# ASP.NET MVC 2: What Model property datatype will autobind an html select (DDL) with multiple selections?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, model-binding

The customer has a Model property that requires a comma separated list of selected options.  We present their select list (DDL) as a multi-choice drop down.

What would the property datatype look like that would autobind multi-selections in the client side HTML select (DDL)?

The select posts data like this:

```
myOptions=Volvo&myOptions=Mercedes&myOptions=Audi
```

And we want to automagically bind it back to some property:

```
IList<string> CarChoices {get;set;}
```

So the POST action method parameter would be `(Carform myForm)`
which would have `myForm.CarChoices` which includes a List of the three selected cars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish but I think this post from Phil Haack describes how to do what you're attempting to do in a clean way:  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is just easier to get your hands dirty and work with the HTML. I suggest doing something like this:

```
<select multiple>
   <% foreach(var item in Model){ %>
      <option value="<%= item.ID %>"><%= item.Description %></option>
   <% } %>
</select>
```

obviously your model is your collection. You can also use the ViewData["Whatever"] object to pass data as well, your choice.

Comment: That's a good start.  I think the data coming back would be myOptions=Volvo&myOptions=Mercedes&myOptions=Audi.  How would we turn this set of values back in to a Model property (and what would it look like?)

Comment: Yeah so when it comes back it is going to look like Volvo,Mercedes,Audi and then you are going to have to parse that using a split function or whatever.

Comment: give the select list a name like name="CarSelections" and then in your controller add String CarSelections and you will see the list